# How to find out the highest level managers for an employee?

Tags: oracle, hive

I have a SQL query where we display the different level's of managers of an employee. For an example
below employees are reporting to given hierarchy:

1. Som(agent)>Piter(supervisor)>Michael (Managers)> John (senior manager)
2. Mike(supervisor)>Iris(Managers)

I want a query to find out the highest level manager an employee is reporting to.
Like the query should result as
Som-John
Mike-Iris

Please suggest any idea to get the above result though oracle query.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Probably want to use a CONNECT BY query to build the tree and then look for the lowest/highest level, depending on which way you built the tree. Can also use the connect path and take the first and last values from it

Comment: If you want a specific query, please edit your question and share your table structure and expected output.